# How to convert form data (text/plain) to json with node?

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, express

I need to execute a POST call to an API to placce an order. Herefore I made a simple Node js app. At the moment with this current state I receive text/plain data into our app, but this is not in JSON style.

This is what I have now:

```
TypeOrder=buy
Coin=BTC
AmountCoin=1
CoinPriceInEuro=100
CoinAddress=17J6W29E2q94YNg5eiaHGsNWW9oJxsWu1M
PaymentMethod=1
GeneralTermsAccepted=true
```

I want it in JSON (like):

```
{
  "Email": "example1@1.nl",
  "Coin": "BTC",
  "CouponCode": "",
  "AmountEuro": 80.0,
  "AmountCoin": 1.0,
   "CoinPriceInEuro": 80,
  "CoinAddress": "17J6W29E2q94YNg5eiaHGsNWW9oJxsWu1M",
  "TypeOrder": "buy",
  "PaymentMethod": 1,
  "GeneralTermsAccepted": false
}
```

And attached you find the code.

Can anyone tell what I have to do in order to get it in right json?

```js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();
const fs=require('fs');
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

fs.readFile('index.html', (err, html) => {
 if(err) {
     throw err;
 }

 var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
     res.statusCode=200;
     res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
     res.write(html);
     res.end();
 });

 server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
     console.log('Server started on port'+port);
 });

 // POST /login gets urlencoded bodies
        app.post('http://localhost:3030/rest/v1/PostOrder', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
            console.log(req.body);
            if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
            res.send('http://localhost:3030/rest/v1/PostOrder', {qs:req.query});
        });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form enctype="text/plain" action="http://localhost:3030/rest/v1/PostOrder" method="POST">
  Buy/Sell:<br>
  <input type="text" name="TypeOrder" value="buy">
  <br>
  Coin:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Coin" value="BTC">

  Amount in Coin:<br>
  <input type="number" name="AmountCoin" value="1">
  <br>
  Coin Price in Euro:<br>
  <input type="number" name="CoinPriceInEuro" value="100">
  <br>
  Coin address to send:<br>
  <input type="text" name="CoinAddress" value="17J6W29E2q94YNg5eiaHGsNWW9oJxsWu1M">
  <br>
  Payment method:<br>
  <input type="radio" name="PaymentMethod" value="1" checked> iDeal<br>
  <input type="radio" name="PaymentMethod" value="2"> Credit Card<br>
  <input type="radio" name="PaymentMethod" value="3"> PayPal<br>
  <br>
  Terms accepted:<br>
  <input type="radio" name="GeneralTermsAccepted" value="true" checked>Ja<br>
  <input type="radio" name="GeneralTermsAccepted" value="false">No<br>
  <br><br>


  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>

</body>
</htm
```

Answer (score 2):

The body data is separated by `\n`, so you can split and then loop over that array.

- The `payload_template` is your empty template that will be filled with the body data.

**Snippet**

```js
let body = `TypeOrder=buy
Coin=BTC
AmountCoin=1
CoinPriceInEuro=100
CoinAddress=17J6W29E2q94YNg5eiaHGsNWW9oJxsWu1M
PaymentMethod=1
GeneralTermsAccepted=true`;

let payload = {};
body.split('\n').forEach((c) => [key, payload[key]] = c.split('='));
console.log(payload);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Comment: why hardcoded? I need the formdata to captured as json in the payload not a hardcoded example

Comment: @user3394645 ok, do you dynamic json transformation.  A minute please!

Answer (score 1):

So, you can do something like the following:

```
const data = `
    TypeOrder=buy
    Coin=BTC
    AmountCoin=1
    CoinPriceInEuro=100
    CoinAddress=17J6W29E2q94YNg5eiaHGsNWW9oJxsWu1M
    PaymentMethod=1
    GeneralTermsAccepted=true`;

let parts = data.split( '\n' );
let formattedData = {};

parts.forEach( ( part ) => {
    const splitData = part.split( '=' );
    formatterData[ splitData[ 0 ] ] = splitData[ 1 ];
} );
```

This is a very simple approach. You can make it more functionally oriented or simpler using a tonne of libraries. :)

Comment: why hardcoded? I need the formdata to captured as json in the payload not a hardcoded example

Comment: It's just an example which will work regardless of the data you have.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to specify the enctype as text/plain in your form.

Just remove that properly since your node app is already using json encoder as a middleware.

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```js
let str=`TypeOrder=buy
Coin=BTC
AmountCoin=1
CoinPriceInEuro=100
CoinAddress=17J6W29E2q94YNg5eiaHGsNWW9oJxsWu1M
PaymentMethod=1
GeneralTermsAccepted=false`;

let result=str.split('\n').reduce((re, v) => {
  let key=v.split('=')[0],val=v.split('=')[1];    
    if (val.match(/^\d+\.\d+$|^\d+$/)) {
      val=Number(val);
    }else if(val.match(/^true$/i)){
      val=true;
    }else if(val.match(/^false$/i)){
      val=false;
    }    
    re[key]=val;
    return re;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: why hardcoded? I need the formdata to captured as json in the payload not a hardcoded example